# Backbone.js: Clicking U.I list elements to show them in a different section of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am working on a project in Backbone.js were I get the results from a Food API and then display them. I have this piece of functionality working. The next piece of functionality I need is to be able to  click an item from the results list and be able to save that result, showing it in the foods tracked list on the right side of the page. The foods tracked list would show the information about the Food (Food Name, Brand and Calories) as well as a total amount of calories from all the foods tracked. I am having trouble creating this functionality because I do not know how to click a list item and have it take the item information in the html list element and place it in another part of the page.

Here is my JSfiddle link- https://jsfiddle.net/Tiquismiquis/2nLezvmg/3/

Here is my JAVASCRIPT-

```
$(function(){

var SearchList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    initialize: function(){
        this.bind("reset", function(model, options){
        console.log("Inside event");
        console.log(model);
        });
    },
    //** 1. Function "parse" is a Backbone function to parse the response properly
    parse:function(response){
        //** return the array inside response, when returning the array
        //** we left to Backone populate this collection
        return response.hits;
    }

});

// The main view of the application
var App = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: 'body',

    events: {
    "input #searchBox" : "prepCollection",
    "click li" : "track"
    },

    initialize: function () {

        this.model = new SearchList();
        this.prepCollection =_.debounce(this.prepCollection, 1000);

        this.$list = $('#listing');
        // this.saved =$('#tracked');

    },

    prepCollection: function(){
        var name = $('input').val();
        var newUrl = "https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search/" + name + "?results=0%3A20&cal_min=0&cal_max=50000&fields=item_name,brand_name,item_id,nf_calories&appId=26952a04&appKey=private_key";

       if (name == ""){
        this.$list.html("")
       }
       else{
        this.model.url = newUrl;
        this.model.fetch({
            success: function (response, xhr) {
                console.log("Inside success");
                console.log(response.toJSON());
            },
            error: function (errorResponse) {
                console.log(errorResponse)
            }
        });
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'sync', this.render);
       }

    },

    // track: function(){
    // },


    render: function(){
        var terms = this.model;
        var wordhtml = "";
        terms.each(function (term) {
            wordhtml = wordhtml + "<li>" +"<strong>" + term.get('fields')["item_name"] + '</strong>'+ ' ('+ term.get('fields')["brand_name"] + ')'+' - '+ term.get('fields')["nf_calories"] + ' Calories' + "</li>"
        }, this);
        this.$list.html(wordhtml);

    }
});
       var app = new App();
});
```

Here is my HTML-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Food Guide App</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <h1>Interactive Food Guide</h1>
                <input type="text" id="searchBox"> <br/><br/>
                <ul id="listing"></ul>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <h1>Foods Tracked</h1>
                <ul id="tracked"></ul>
                <p id="total">total calories: <span>0</span></p>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Backbone and Underscore -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.2.1/backbone-min.js"></script>
    <!-- apps functionality -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: there are many ways to do it - backbone way by creating a listView, or simply put what you need in `data-` attributes and get using `.attr` in the click handler. Can you create a fiddle to play with ?

Comment: never add `appKeys/Ids` on a public platform, for now I've edited the question and removed them.

Comment: Here is my JSfiddle- https://jsfiddle.net/Tiquismiquis/2nLezvmg/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do it - through a backbone listView or simply by adding `data-*` attributes to the element.

Below is an example demonstrating the latter :

Template change :

```
var liTemplate = '<li data-brand="<%-data.brand_name%>" data-name="<%-data.item_name%>"><strong><%-data.item_name%> (<%-data.brand_name%>)</strong></li>';

wordhtml = _.template(liTemplate)({ data : term.get('fields')});
```

View change :

```
events:{
  'click li': 'track'
},
track: function(e){
  var $target = $(e.currentTarget);
  var itemName = $target.attr('data-name');
  var brandName = $target.attr('data-brand');
  //do whatever you need
}
```

Find the working fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/nitincool4urchat/2nLezvmg/8/

Comment: Now I get the error- Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined

Comment: see how I've structured the template, it contains `data.` fields which are passed through `_.template`. Let me try to create a working fiddle.